# How to transfer files from remote server to local server

Tags: networking, server, vpn, localhost

On the client side, I am using a NanoPi which is connected to a local network. And my server is connected to a global IP.

My application demands transfer of some files from the server to the nano pi.

I am trying this

```
ssh user1@<global ip> 'scp /home/user1/testFile 192.168.1.32:/root/'
```

To which I need to add the nanopi device's IP into the host file of the server. And since the nanopi is on the local network, the connection won't be made.

Is there any solution for the file transfer? Can VPN work here?

Comment: VPN could work here but going the other way round (initiating the transfer from the NanoPi) would be easier.

Comment: As Melebius said, just use `scp user@server1:path/to/source path/to/destination`.  Add any switches you like for recursivity,...

Comment: do you want `[ThePC]--send command-->[Server]--copyFile-->[NanoPI]` ?

Comment: Here, you have a PC, which might be on the local network as well as connected to the internet, a remote server and the nanoPi, also on the local network. If this is the case, you could create an SSH tunnel from remote server to nanoPi via your desktop. From server: `ssh -N -L localhost:1025:nanoPi:22 user@your_pc_internet_ip` then, do `scp -P1025 /home/user1/testFile nanoPi_user@localhost:/root` You might have to open port 22 on your internet router for this to work, if so, only allow IP of server.

Comment: @cmak.fr Yes. Somewhat similar to what you have mentioned. Once the [NanoPi] receives a message about updates, it secure copies or downloads the file from the production server